# Need to return matched data from mongo db JSON

Tags: mongodb

I have Json which have values like state_city details this contains information like which city belongs to which state -

Need to query it for particular state name which will gives me all cities that belongs to that state.

db.collection.find({
  "count": 10,
  "state.name": "MP"
})

```
[
  {
    "collection": "collection1",
    "count": 10,
    "state": [
      {
        "name": "MH",
        "city": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "name": "MH",
        "city": "Pune"
      },
      {
        "name": "UP",
        "city": "Kanpur"
      },
      {
        "name": "CG",
        "city": "Raipur"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "collection": "collection2",
    "count": 20,
    "state": [
      {
        "name": "MP",
        "city": "Indore"
      },
      {
        "name": "MH",
        "city": "Bhopal"
      },
      {
        "name": "UP",
        "city": "Kanpur"
      },
      {
        "name": "CG",
        "city": "Raipur"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of a single json document in your collection? What you pasted is not making sense.

Comment: @Bajal Corrected it, Hope this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use aggregate query to get only matching elements in array :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$content.state"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "content.state.name": "MH",
      "count": 10
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$content.state.city",
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      key: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      cities: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      cities: 1
    }
  }
])
```

This query will return :

```js
{
  "cities": [
    "Pune",
    "Mumbai"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the JSON , I have count as unique element and want to found all cities based on the state and count for example . Get all cities whose state is MH and count is 10.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would be the solution.

```
db.collection.find({ "count": 10, "state":{"name": "MP"}})
```

For more complex queries, *$elemMatch* is also available.